# Showing two long cards side by side android

Tags: usability-testing

How do I show two different summary text boxes side by side in a UI?

[image]This is a screenshot from a screen I'm working on for a social justice app. This screen is meant to show messages from both the defence and the prosecuting counsel, but now the client has added that these messages could be up to 1000 characters, and this interface would break at that implementation. I currently need ideas on how this can be done. I would ideally prefer side by side since it's more of a comparism flow and putting one above the other might create some bias. But all solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make the layout neutral. By placing one on the left/first and another on the right/second you created priority.

In the side asked court to rule on some issue, prosecution in criminal cases; plaintiff in civil cases presents the case first. Opposition speaks second. It is a dialog, opposition answers to the moving party. It makes sense to display the answer second. Consider using dialog-like presentation for closing statements.

[image]